# How to make dynamic states and add buttons to it in Flex using NOT MXML but Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, components, states

I'm making a sort of EPOS system but i'm stuck.

I know how to add stages in actionscript but i don't know how to add children to them stages.

This is how I make my states.

```
var state1:State = new State();
state1.name = "state1";
states.push(state1);
```

And this is how I make my buttons and try to add them

```
var prodBTN:Button = new Button();
prodBTN.id = products[i].id;
prodBTN.label = products[i].name.toString();
state1.overrides[new AddChild(prodBTN)];
```

It would be nice if anyone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Greetz,
Gizzy

Comment: Do you want to do this w/ Spark components or Halo/MX components?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this but from your example shouldn't it be

`state1.overrides.push(new AddChild(prodBTN));`